# Removing workflow pause causes this error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I've inherited a Document Set workflow where I'm trying understand better why it has the or even needs the pause. Research tells me there is a bug in SP2010 that would cause unwanted document versions so I'm wondering if this is why the pause is being used. Regardless, when I remove the pause the workflow immediately goes into error. And if I remove the "Capture a version of the Document Set..." line it works ok but of course doesn't create the version needed. I'm wondering if there is another way to avoid using the pause. *Can anyone shed some possible light for me?*

The error is:
**The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.**

Below is the section of this workflow.

[image]

Thanks for the help!